# BufferedImage leaks - are there any alternatives?

Tags: java, image, memory-leaks, bufferedimage

I am having strange problems with BufferedImage, which in some cases consumes all the free system memory (3GB, 1.5GB free).

I have created a simple wrapper and I use it like this:

```
public ImageWrapper(final byte[] bytes) throws ImageWrapperException {
    this(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
}



public ImageWrapper(final ByteArrayInputStream bis) throws ImageWrapperException {
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(bis);
        bis.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new ImageWrapperException(e);
    }
}
```

(I have jsut verified that it happens even with `image = ImageIO.read(file);`)

I am not getting any exceptions until the first "Cannot allocate memory".

For some reason, when reading specific type of images, the reading of the image will end up with all the system memory consumed. I am not talking about heap, but really the system memory.

It happens only in certain environments - it does not happen on my **OSX**, but it happens on my **Debian** server.

1. Do you have an idea why this could be happening?
2. Are there any alternatives to BufferedImage, possibly working better?
3. The problematic machine is a Virtual Server. Can it be caused by its configuration?

Thanks

EDIT:

1. Example image: http://cl.ly/1P430l0V1g133r0C291J
2. It is just the first and only instance which will produce this.
3. I have just verified that it also happens with: `image = ImageIO.read(file);` - I am starting to think, that it must be something outside of Java - some native library which is buggy...

EDIT2:

So the problem is with the FileSystem - where I have a 7GB directory with thousands of images inside. When I try to read a file, it consumes all the memory - I suppose it is some kind of Filesystem issue.

Comment: What specific type of image? Can you post a binary 1:1 copy of one such image? How do you use `ImageWrapper` in your surrounding code, how many instances, etc.? Post some more code please.

Comment: Especially if you resize, split the ImageIO.read into using the first ImageReader available for the image type. This circumvents the BufferedImage memory usage. BTW. do bis.close() in a finally block.

Comment: Philipp: See my updates. Joop: This happens even without any resizing or saving. Even if I did not do bis.close(), I don't see any reason, why the process would consume 1.5 GB of memory.

Comment: @Vojtěch: how *exactly* do you measure the memory usage? Memory measurements on Linux are not as straight-forward as they seem...

Comment: Are you saying that if you write a class that has a main method

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Image image = ImageIO.read(args[0]);
}

And pass in the filename of the image you linked, it reproduces this for you?

Comment: I haven't had time to test it separately, but that is the moment, when my application and also my server gets completely out of memory. Will try to do that today.

Comment: thkala: I don't measure it - when it happens, I can't even write "ls" in bash as even Bash complains about "Cannot allocate memory".

Comment: Weird... have you confirmed this with a non-Java program? E.g. using `dd` or `cat`? I'd be really interested to know the cause of this issue.

Comment: Non-java problems are okay - even reading the file with Java seems to be okay. The problem is really with the BufferedImage :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is definitely something wrong with BufferedImage - I've tested it on two servers and it was leaking with the same results - System completely out of memory.

In the end I've written a simple wrapper over PHP and I now use GD for image manipulation. Works fine now. Thanks for all the suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

There are some known bugs related to ImageIO.read() and BufferedImage

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7166379

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6716560

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the code to `java.nio` and `memory mapped file` access. Those are stored outside the heap.

This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023200/memory-mapped-files-in-java) is interesting.

Comment: The problem was not in the heap, there was some problem in native code as the whole system  was running out of memory.