# How to diagnose OutOfMemoryErrors in Tomcat 7?

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, tomcat7

I have several applications running in a Tomcat7 instance.

Once in a while, I notice that there are OutOfMemoryErrors in the log.

How can I find out, which application (ideally - which) class causes them?

**Update 1 (25.12.2014 11:44 MSK):**

I changed something in the application (added a shutdown call to a Quartz scheduler, when the servlet context is destroyed), which may have caused memory leaks.

Now my memory consumption charts look like shown below.

[image: Memory consumption charts]

Does any of them indicate memory leaks in the application?

If yes, which one?

Comment: Keep in mind that it is usually never as simple as a single class causing it; if you dig into this you do it with the least amount of tunnel vision as you can possibly manage. The OutOfMemory might also happen for valid reasons - that your heap simply isn't big enough for the amount that all joined applications need at a specific peak moment in time.

Answer (score 3):

There is a good documentation about that http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/clopts-139448.html

- create a heapdump with the vm parameters described in the link above.
- analyze this heapdump, for example use memoryanalzyer(https://eclipse.org/mat/).

Answer (score 1):

**OOM** can occur because of many reasons.

1.) Memory Leaks

2.) Generation of a large number of local variables etc.

`OOM` is a common indication of a memory leak. Essentially, the error is thrown when there’s insufficient space to allocate a new object.

Few Exception Messages

1. java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2. java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
3. java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
4. java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: request  bytes for . Out of swap space?
5. java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:   (Native method)

More detailed information [here](http://www.toptal.com/java/hunting-memory-leaks-in-java) and [official](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memleaks-137499.html)

refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854868/how-to-troubleshoot-out-of-memory-error-on-production-system/10855292#10855292) and [this](http://blog.jeroenreijn.com/2010/10/large-heap-dump-analysis-with-eclipse.html)

Need to analyze the Heap dump/thread dumps etc.

[Detecting Memory leak](http://java.dzone.com/articles/monitoring-and-detecting)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jmap . It will give snap shot of java process.

How many objects in memory with size of objects .

```
jmap -histo #processID
```